# issue with Blueprints API, addVertex

Tags: scala, orientdb

I've just got an issue with the BluePrints API.
I've executed the following Scala commands:

```
val dbBasename = "C:\\Users\\taatoal1\\tmp\\orientdb\\databases\\"
val dbpath = "test_ingest"
val (uname, pwd) = ("admin", "admin")

val graph = new OrientGraph(s"plocal:$dbpath", uname, pwd)
graph.addVertex("class:Employee")
```

and I got the following error

```
<console>:14: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method addVertex in class OrientBaseGraph of type (x$1: Any, x$2: <repeated...>[Object])com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex
and  method addVertex in class OrientBaseGraph of type (x$1: Any)com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex
match argument types (String)
              graph.addVertex("class:Employee")
                    ^
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found out that there is another version of `addVertex` that takes two strings as parameters: the class name and the cluster name.